# A tricky tensor

Tags: tensors

There's this question from Schaum's Outlines-Tensor Calculus:

If the $a_{ij}$ are constants, calculate the partial derivative $\partial\over\partial x_k$$(a_{ij}x_ix_j)$.

We use the product rule and the fact that $\partial x_p \over \partial x_q$=$\delta_{pq}$.

$\partial\over\partial x_k$$(a_{ij}x_ix_j) =a_{ij}$$\partial\over\partial x_k$$(x_ix_j)$=$a_{ij}$$(x_j$$\partial x_i\over\partial x_k$$+$ $x_i$$\partial x_j\over x_k$$)$

$=a_{ij}(x_j\delta_{ik}+ x_i\delta_{jk})=a_{kj}x_j+a_{ik}x_{i}$

$=(a_{ik}+a_{ki})x_i
$

What i don't understand is how $a_{kj}x_j+a_{ik}x_{i}$ came to be $(a_{ik}+a_{ki})x_i
$

I'm still in the introduction so be gentle with your answers :)

Comment: $a_{kj}x_{j}=a_{ki}x_{i}$ just by renaming the dummy variable $j$ to $i$.  (Remember that repeated indices are summed over.)

Comment: Can $(a_{ik}+a_{ki})x_i$=$2a_{ik}x_i$??

Comment: Yes if $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$.